# Docker cannot access exposed port inside container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a container for which I expose my port to access a service running within the container. I am not exposing my ports outside the container i.e. to the host (using host network on mac). On getting inside the container using `exec -t` and running a curl for a post request, I get the error:

`curl command: curl http://localhost:19999`
`Failed connect to localhost:19999; Connection refused`.

I have the expose command in my dockerfile and do not want to expose ports to my host. My service is also up and running inside the container. I also have the property within config set as
`"ExposedPorts": {"19999/tcp": {}}`
(obtained through `docker inspect <container id/name>\ Any idea on why this is not working? Using docker for Mac

I'd post my docker-compose file too but this is being built through maven. I can ensure that I am exposing my port using 19999:19999. Another weird issue is that on disabling my proxies it would run a very light weight command for my custom service and wouldn't run it again returning the same error as above. The issue only occurs on my machine and not others

Comment: Can you verify that you can access the app by forwarding the port to the docker host?

Comment: Please provide code snippets, for docker file curl command and server side code

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**
The app must be listening on port `19999` which is probably not.
The `EXPOSE` that you're using inside the Dockerfile does nothing.

Usually there is no need to change the default port on which an application is listening, hence each container has its own IP and you shouldn't run in a port conflict.

**Answer:**
Instead of curling `19999` try to use the default port on which your app would normally be listening to(it's hard to guess what you are trying to run).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't *publish* a port (with the `docker run -p` option or the Docker Compose `ports:` option), you cannot directly reach the container on Docker for Mac.  See the [Known limitations, use cases, and workarounds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds) in the Docker Desktop for Mac documentation: the "per-container IP addressing is not possible" item ism what you're trying to attempt.

The `docker inspect` IP address is basically useless, except in one very specific Docker configuration (on a native-Linux host, calling from outside of Docker, on the same host); I wouldn't bother looking it up.

The Dockerfile `EXPOSE` directive and similar runtime options do very little and mostly serve as documentation.  Even if you have that configured you still need to separately publish the port when you start the container to reach it from outside of Docker space.